# Dropped the laptop, now this happened... What did I break?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

I dropped my laptop. Since then, when I turn it on, as soon as Windows boots up, the screen becomes greenish and grainy. *(In Linux live usb the computer (or screen) freezes after warm up).*

If I press down on the bottom left corner of the laptop on a soft surface like a mattress while holding down the laptop from the right side so that it doesn't prop up from the pressure (basically flexing it), the screen turns normal. If I let go, it becomes bad again.

If I disable my dedicated/discrete graphic card (ATI) through device manager, the screen turns normal.

From the above, l figured the impact probably dislodged the graphic card, so I openes up the laptop and removed the heat sink to see. Everything looked normal. I checked to see if the chip came loose, but it was firm and secure. I don't see how it could have dislodged given it's physical shape on the board.
I changed the thermal paste and bolted everything back up. Turned the laptop on, nothing changed.

What did I break? How do I troubleshoot this?

Thanks a mill for any help!

Comment: Could have dislodged a connector, either in the actual display panel itself or at the motherboard.

Comment: Try attaching an external screen to your computer and see if that works. It appears the damage is the screen and the ribbon connection from the screen to the computer. The screen includes all the components related to lighting the screen.

Comment: If it's the screen, then why would it normalize when I disable the graphic card?

Comment: You said  "Everything looked normal. I checked to see if the chip came loose, but it was firm and secure. ....  Turned the laptop on, nothing changed"   Also I made mention of the connector wire. If you need a true estimate of the damage, it may be best to take it to a local repair shop.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could refer me to a repair shop that's compenent enough. The reason I ask here is cz I failed finding one. Also, since this is the internet, there's a much higher chance sum1 who has experience with this particular issue coming forth w/ help. Whereas, a repair shop is a single person who if h/she hadn't come accross this particular problem, & thus have experience handling it, you're out of luck. But that's not the problem, it would be nice if they tell you straight up "IDK". It's the making things worse / waste ur time & money / wrong diagnosis that's the bigger issue.

Comment: @JJrussel - How exactly do we do that without you giving away your location.  Do not give us that information.  We will not provide a recommendation for a repair shop.

Comment: @Ramhound swoosh

Comment: Most repair shops won't charge you if they can't fix the problem or they will give you a quote ahead of time.

Comment: @Ramhound Like I said, not competent enough. Thanks for dropping by 